# Why is the summarize() function in the "srvyr" package outputing a tibble of lists?

Tags: r, survey, summarize, census

I'm trying to use the "srvyr" package in R to analyze American Community Survey Public Use Microdata (PUMS). I'm using a script an old colleague gave me as a base and trying to piece my way forward. Because I've seen the script in action before--and I've looked through the srvyr ReadMe--I think the output I'm getting isn't as it's supposed to be.

PUMS has weights and replicate weights. This is a simplified version of what the data looks like and a simple summary one could make.

```
x <- tibble(serialno = c("1","2","3","4"),
            puma = c("1","1","2","2"),
            bld = c("1","3","2","2"),
            wgtp = c(56,16,16,37),
            wgtp1 = c(18,14,15,59))
x_design <- x %>% 
  as_survey_rep(weights="wgtp",
                repweights=starts_with("wgtp"),
                type="JK1") 
table <- x_design %>%
  group_by(bld) %>%
  summarize(tot=survey_total())
```

When I've seen script like this before, the output is a tibble with variables and values. But when I run this code (and a more complex version than what's above), the output is a tibble of lists.

```
> table
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  out$bld  $tot $tot_se
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1          56   26.9 
2 2          53   14.8 
3 3          16    1.41
```

If I call table$out, I get the output I want.

```
> table$out
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  bld     tot tot_se
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1        56  26.9 
2 2        53  14.8 
3 3        16   1.41
```

Why is this happening and how can I ensure I end up with the latter output rather than the former, without using $ operator?

I understand tbl_svy objects themselves have elements one can extract (e.g. x$variables extracts a dataframe), but I wasn't expecting to have to extract the output after using the srvyr::summarize function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I run the above code as it is I get a tibble back with 3 rows and 3 columns. There is no `table$out` present for me. However, I do get warning message `Warning message:
In svrepdesign.default(variables = variables, repweights = repweights,  :
  scale (n-1)/n not provided: guessing n=number of replicates`

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. That output is what I would expect. The warning results from the simplified survey design that leaves some arguments unspecified. The unexpected output I'm experiencing (tibble of lists) appears when I run both a simplified example (like you did) and a more complicated version on a more fully specified tbl_svy object. So, the simplified survey design called out in the warning isn't an issue, I think. Given that you can't reproduce table$out, I'm guessing my problem is local. I tried removing and reinstalling the packages, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got to the results you show last, but you can remove `$` with the function `unpack` of tidyr

You can try with this:

```
table <- table %>% 
  tidyr::unpack(out)
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Assuming I can't get the package to do what it's supposed to do (i.e. output a tibble of variables and values, rather than of lists), I'll add unpack() to my workflow as a workaround.